# Trying to find proper profiler to test consumption after build on unity

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, profiling, performance-testing, game-development

I have problem on my game after I build it and install on my device it's lagging and has low fps(I tested on different devices and everywhere is the same). I tried unity's built in profiler which shows that everything is fine and always displays 100(or more) fps. So I think profiling game after installation can help me, but I can't find any proper profiler to use and can someone give me any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Unity's profiler ? Like what do you want more than it doesn't do ?

Comment: I want to profile performance after build, I mean profiling without unity, because unity profiler tell's shows info based on my pc's cpu and i wanna be aware of my mobiles real consuption

Comment: But using Unity remote, you can debug ON your mobile

Comment: Nope, it works very different way

Answer (score 1):

Unity's profiler is still a valid tool. You can find the slow parts in your scripts.

The main difference on mobile devices are bad graphic cards. 
To have good performance on those cards you need to bring down the polygon count and number of draw calls.

You find those infos in the stats window of the Game tab.

Also mobile shaders and baked lighting helps.

Find more hints in Unity's [Mobile Optimization Guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimizationPracticalGuide.html).

Comment: sorry but this article is not as useful as I need to be

Comment: There is also a profiler-specific page that could help you: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileProfiling.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at Graphy plugin. May be it will be useful in your case.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/graphy-ultimate-fps-counter-stats-monitor-debugger-105778